# How can I sort a numpy array according to its column values?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
>>> array_text[:10]
array([[1, 52.51, 12, 0],
    [1, 52.52, 52, 2],
    [1, 52.53, 1, 6],
    [2, 52.51, 20, 0],
    [2, 52.52, 75, 76],
    [2, 52.53, 6, 33],
    [3, 52.51, 84, 0],
    [3, 52.52, 39, 68],
    [3, 52.53, 0, 13],
    [4, 52.51, 1, 0]], dtype=object)
```

What I want to do is to sort it according to its second column, in descending order. So the result I want will be:

```
>>> array_text[:10]
array([[1, 52.53, 1, 6],
    [1, 52.52, 52, 2],
    [1, 52.51, 12, 0],
    [2, 52.53, 6, 33],
    [2, 52.52, 75, 76],
    [2, 52.51, 20, 0],
    [3, 52.53, 0, 13],
    [3, 52.52, 39, 68],
    [3, 52.51, 84, 0],
    [4, 52.51, 1, 0]], dtype=object)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean, maintain the ascending order of the first column and sort in descending order in the second columns for each value in the first?

Comment: @James Yes! That's what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.lexsort`. The trick to reversing column here comes by multiplying with -1.

```
import numpy as np
arr[np.lexsort((-1*arr[:,1], arr[:,0]))]
```

Ouput:

```
array([[1, 52.53, 1, 6],
       [1, 52.52, 52, 2],
       [1, 52.51, 12, 0],
       [2, 52.53, 6, 33],
       [2, 52.52, 75, 76],
       [2, 52.51, 20, 0],
       [3, 52.53, 0, 13],
       [3, 52.52, 39, 68],
       [3, 52.51, 84, 0],
       [4, 52.51, 1, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have learned a lot from it!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this is using pandas, since the functionality is already built into the data frame using the `sort_values` method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 52.51, 12, 0],
              [1, 52.52, 52, 2],
              [1, 52.53, 1, 6],
              [2, 52.51, 20, 0],
              [2, 52.52, 75, 76],
              [2, 52.53, 6, 33],
              [3, 52.51, 84, 0],
              [3, 52.52, 39, 68],
              [3, 52.53, 0, 13],
              [4, 52.51, 1, 0]], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=list('ABCD'))
df.sort_values(['A', 'B'], ascending=[True, False]).values
# returns:
array([[1, 52.53, 1, 6],
       [1, 52.52, 52, 2],
       [1, 52.51, 12, 0],
       [2, 52.53, 6, 33],
       [2, 52.52, 75, 76],
       [2, 52.51, 20, 0],
       [3, 52.53, 0, 13],
       [3, 52.52, 39, 68],
       [3, 52.51, 84, 0],
       [4, 52.51, 1, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I made the array from a dataframe, so your answer is really helpful as well! It's a shame that I can choose only one helpful answer!